# MediaSource.CreateFromUri(...) cannot retrieve the file for MediaSource.

Tags: c#, uwp

Here is my code........

```
public  MediaPlaybackItem GetMediaPlaybackItemFromPath(string path)
        {
            //StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
            var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(path));

            return new MediaPlaybackItem(source);
        }
```

If I use this method I cannot play music. But if I try this I can play music.

```
public async Task<MediaPlaybackItem> GetMediaPlaybackItemFromPathAsync(string path)
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
            var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);

            return new MediaPlaybackItem(source);
        }
```

Whats the problem with this? I am using mediaplaybacklist for MediaPlayer.Source . How can I get proper MediaSource using my first method? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not pass file path parameter to  `CreateFromUri` directly. In general, the Uri parameter is `http` protocol address such as `http://www.testvideo.com/forkvideo/test.mp4`. But we could pass the file path with uwp file access [uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes).

For example:

**Media file stored in the installation folder.**

`ms-appx:///`

**Local folder.**

`ms-appdata:///local/`

**Temporary folder.**

`ms-appdata:///temp/`

For more you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about if I have a file in the different location?

Comment: There a lot of limit in uwp, if your file was not stored in the above location, and  the better way is use `CreateFromStorageFile`.

Comment: In WinUI3, I have tried ms-appx:/// in code, it did not work, but if putting the source in xaml, it works.